# Can you change the Outline Colour of a Confusion Matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, seaborn, confusion-matrix

This may be a simple question that can be answered, but is it possible to change the outline colour of a confusion matrix?

Using the code to generate a confusion matrix, it has no outline:

```
cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(y, predictions)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12))
sns.heatmap(cm, ax=ax, cbar=False, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='gist_yarg', linewidths=0.1)
ax.set_xticklabels(['a','b']);
ax.set_yticklabels(['a','b']);
ax.set_xlabel('my_label')
ax.set_ylabel('my_label')
```

My confusion matrix generates, but it has no outline - so it is possible to change the outline to a solid colour like black?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the line color is white so you don't see it with the `gist_yarg` colorscheme, you can set it using `linecolor=` :

```
from sklearn import metrics
import seaborn as sns

y = np.random.choice([0,1],50)
predictions = np.random.choice([0,1],50)

cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(y, predictions)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
sns.heatmap(cm, ax=ax, cbar=False, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='gist_yarg', 
linewidths=0.1,linecolor='lightblue')
```

[image]